# Eagle create library remove "direction" in symbol

Tags: eaglecad

I am making a library in eagle, and I am currently working on the symbol. I made pins, but they all show a small "direction":[image: 1]

which shows up in little green lettering next to the pin, like this: [image]

I cant figure out how to remove it. Does anybody know? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those green circles and direction markings only show up in the symbol view and no longer show up in the schematic when the library is used.   Here is an example.

---

This is the symbol view of a part in a library:

[image]

And this is the symbol when it is actually implemented in a schematic:

[image]

I assume you don't care about these markings in the design view of your part symbol as the users of your library will not see these markings.